# Primitive Matrix Whose Square has Fewer Positive Entries

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, soft-question

This is a bit of an open question but I wanted to see if someone had any insight about this.  I have a primitive matrix

$$
A \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

which has the peculiar property that $A^2$ has fewer positive entries than the original matrix $A$.  We can see that

$$
A^2 \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

I was curious if there was some overarching property that allows $A^2$ to have fewer positive entries than $A$.  Is this a property that seems to be particular to this matrix, or is there a certain class of matrices that hold this property?  I know this is a bit of soft question, but I mean for it to be exploratory.

Comment: Certainly, if $A$ is *strictly upper triangular*, then $A^n$ will generally have fewer non-zero entries than $A^{n-1}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That is a good point, and I suppose the bottom left entry has less of an impact to add positive entries under multiplication relative to the size of the matrix.

Comment: In particular, the principal submatrix of $A$ whereby we delete the first and last rows/columns is strictly upper triangular, which means that this particular submatrix will have a decreasing number of non-zero entries as we look at the powers of $A$.

Comment: Your matrix is not primitive.